# Scroll div block instead of window scroll in mobile browsers (Android,Safari,Chrome,Firefox)

Tags: css, scroll, height, overflow, infinite-scroll

I have to scroll `div` block instead of window scroll and i want that this block will be until the end of the page, and if it is longer then scroll - it must appear.

I have such  html:

```
<body>
    <div id='header'>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='main'>
            <div id='options'>
            </div>
            <!-- other blocks -->
            <div id='scrorable'> <!-- This div i want to scroll instead of window -->
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And also i use infinite-scroll that works now on window scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200)
    {
        //ajax Call and append income data to html 
    }
});
```

I also need to change this code according to scrolling div (not window).

**Updated**: Infinite scroll issue I sold in that way:

Insert one inner div in my scroll div:

```
<div id='scrorable'>
    <div id='scrorable-inner'> <!--My inner div-->
        <-- content -->
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

And My Changed inner scroll code:

```
$('div#scrorable').scroll(function()
{
        if($('div#scrorable').scrollTop() >= $('div#scrorable-inner').height() - $'div#scrorable').height() - 200)
        {
            //ajax Call and append income data to html 
        }
});
```

**Updated**:

Now i use

```
  $('div#scrorable').height($(window).height()-300);
```

to set height of that block. I use ($(window).height() - height of header and footer (300px))